# Practices value/reference memory in C#

Tags: c#

Imagine we have this method:

```
// By value
private static void ShowMessage(string Message)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", Message);
}
```

Is a good practise pass by value a string only if we want view/show the content?

For example, in a 32-bit system, a string with 20 characters (C# default: UTF-16) the reference is 32 bits, but by value is (20 characters * (2 bytes * 8 bits)) = 320 bits

32 bits vs 320 ...

Answer (score 4):

`string` is a reference type, so even if you pass it by value, it's a reference to the string that is passed, not a copy of the string. So the length of the string has no effect at all on what you pass to the method.

It's really important to understand the difference between value types and reference types, and between passing parameters by value or by reference. I suggest you read [this article](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html), which gives a good explanation.

Comment: Ok, but then if I no use ref, a new object (320 bits) and its reference (32-64 bits) will be reserved. If I use "ref" only for show or copy yo other site, then my program will be more efficiente, no? What do you think?

Comment: @user3602030, no, no new object will be allocated. Only the reference (32/64 bits) is passed. Using `ref` won't make your code faster (at least not in this case). Did you read the article I linked to?

Comment: I've read, but I don't understand it :/ . If no object is created for the local string "Message" and the reference of the original object is passed by value, Why I can't change the value of the original string(object)?

Comment: @user3602030, when you call the ShowMessage method, you pass a copy of a reference to the string. If the ShowMessage changes that reference, it just changes a copy, making it point to another string (or to nothing). The caller still has its own copy, which isn't affected.

Comment: mm... then if I modify the variable (int Message, string Message, MyClass Message, ...), the variable reference to the new object. Correct?

Comment: @user3602030, what do you mean? Which variable are you talking about?

Comment: MyMethod(string Var1, int Var2, MyClass Var3){...} I'm talking about Var1 Var2 and Var3, when I execute the method.

Comment: @user3602030, if you assign Var1, Var2 or Var3 in MyMethod, the caller won't be affected at all. If you change a property of Var3, though, it will be seen by the caller, because MyClass is a reference type, and the caller and callee refer to the same instance. If it was a value type, MyMethod would only be modifying a copy.

Answer (score 2):

You are not passing the whole string by value; `string` is a reference type, so what you are passing by value is a reference to the actual object.

"Reference" is an intentionally vague term in this situation. The implementation actually does pass a pointer to the instance.

Comment: But if it's a reference, why no change the value if I no specify "ref string Message" ?

Comment: @user3602030: Because it's a reference *passed by value*, i.e. you are changing a copy of the reference.

Comment: Ok, the refenre isn't the same (0x555 != 0x777), but both points to the same object, no?

Comment: @user3602030: If it helps you, think of what you are passing as a pointer. Changing the value of the pointer only changes what your copy of the pointer points to. You would need a double pointer to make a change visible from outside; that's what `ref` does.

Comment: Then, the method receive the same memory direction of my real string, but if I modificate its value, the executable/VM creates a new object and asign this direction to Message. Sure?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to use ref only when you need to change your variable content within the method:

```
private static void ShowMessage(ref string text){
    Console.WriteLine(text); // use the old content
    text= "this is the new value"; //the new variable content will override the old one
}
```

You can also use the *out* when the content will be written, but won't be read:

```
private static void ShowMessage(out string text){
    // you can't use the text variable, but you must set it's value
    text= "this is the new value"; //the new variable content will override the old one
}
```

In any other cases, you should use it as any other value variable. As the friends above have said, string is a Reference type in C#. It's the same of using the String (with upper S).

Comment: "out" is only to return values. A good example is when you need to return 2 values of different types (eg. a string and an int). You then can have two parameters "out" like in my example. The value you pass is ignored, and the value you set inside the method will remain to be used by the callers. In the above example, if I call string str=null; ShowMessage(str); Console.WriteLine(str); it will print the new value.

Comment: See comments in @Thomas Levesque post, please.